# Why can't an Alpine Linux-based Docker image find commands to execute at an absolute path?

Tags: docker, unix, rust, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am new to Docker. I want to containerise a small environment so that I can run executables, but I am stuck because I can't even get an executable to run.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
example/
|-Dockerfile
|-hello_world
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Use Alpine Linux as the base image
FROM alpine:latest

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the executable to the container
COPY hello_world /app/

# Set the permissions for the executable
RUN chmod +x /app/hello_world

# Define the command to run your server when the container starts
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/hello_world"]
```

Then I run:

`> sudo docker build -t example .`

`> sudo docker run --name example_container example`

The result of this is this:

`exec /app/hello_world: no such file or directory`

I have tried as many variations on this as I can think, trying to use `CMD`, `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile but all have the same result of the image not being able to find the hello_world program in the app folder that exists at the root.

I am really confused because I tried this on my vanilla Ubuntu OS, I put a test folder at the root and then a `hello_world` in there, and it seemed to work fine that I could run it from wherever with this absolute path.

`/app/hello_world` is an executable, it's a compiled bit of Rust code. When I run `/app/hello_world` in the shell on my Ubuntu machine it works fine.

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu toolchain/rustc 1.71.0

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the first line of `/app/hello_world`? If it has a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) it needs to point to a valid interpreter (and not have e.g. DOS line feeds which confuse the kernel and quite frankly the entire non-Windows world)

Comment: /app/hello_world is an executable, it's a compiled bit of Rust code. When I run /app/hello_world in shell on my Ubuntu machine it works fine, but is there an issue having this as an executable like this?

Comment: How did you compile it, for which architecture? Alpine famously does not use GNU glibc so if you compiled for that, it won't work.

Comment: stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu toolchain/rustc 1.71.0

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information and I'm not familiar enough with Go to solve this. But I'm pretty sure this is relevant information which you should include in the question. As a quick remedy, try compiling statically, or try building inside an Alpine Docker image too.

Comment: Ah, thank you! If I want to use GNU libc still, then can I add that as a shared lib there? I am still confused though, because that is not the error it points to?

Comment: That will likely be an issue. You need to compile it for `x86_64-alpine-linux-musl` rather than `gnu` for alpine to be able to start the exec. Although, i would expect another error than the above one.

Comment: Honestly though, you might be better of starting with another distro just to get started with docker. Debian have `slim` images which should be enough to get you started. Although, I would even expect that you can run your rust app in a `scratch` image even.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with something else and come back to Alpine. Hopefully that solves both issues at the same time:)

Comment: FYI I remade the docker with debian and it worked fine, thanks for the tip:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you see the "no such file or directory" error is because the system is looking for the path embedded in the `.interp` section of the ELF binary. For a binary compiled under glibc, that looks like:

```
$ objdump -j .interp -s hello

hello:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .interp:
 400318 2f6c6962 36342f6c 642d6c69 6e75782d  /lib64/ld-linux-
 400328 7838362d 36342e73 6f2e3200           x86-64.so.2.
```

In your Alpine image, there is no `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which is what leads to the error message.

---

Using a C binary as an example, if I start with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And compile it on my glibc system, then try running it under Alpine, we see:

```
$ podman run -it --rm -v $PWD:/src  -w /src alpine
/src # ./hello
/bin/sh: ./hello: not found
```

If we make the expected interpreter available, like this:

```
$ podman run -it --rm -v $PWD:/src -w /src \
  -v /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  alpine
```

We get a new error:

```
/src # ./hello
./hello: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If we make the necessary shared library available:

```
$ podman run -it --rm -v $PWD:/src -w /src \
  -v /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
  -v /lib64/libc.so.6:/lib64/libc.so.6  alpine
```

Then the command works as expected:

```
/src # ./hello
Hello world.
```

Comment: LOL! This is another reason why static binaries (such as those produced by default by Go) are saner. Shared libraries are the devils work. :-) I say this as someone who was a Unix support engineer around 1990 and had to deal with all of the problems the concept introduced from the customers of the computer manufacturer I worked for. @whatf0xx.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I received, here is an answer for anyone looking to do this with Rust and Alpine.

As pointed out, the issue comes from trying to use the default `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` to compile the Rust binary. Instead, compile with `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` and in particular use:

`rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

Followed by:

`cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

Then add this new binary to the project instead of the old one, and now Alpine will run it just fine.

Comment: Or, just build static binaries. Shared (dynamic) libraries cause more problems than they solve today. Yes, that wasn't true in the 1980's when the concept was first introduced in Windows and then Unix. But it is definitely true today.